# the best overloaded method match for List<T>.Add(T) has some Invalid arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I defined a `List` like this:

```
List<Agahii.Ads> ads = new List<Agahii.Ads>();
```

Then I want to fill it with the result of a LINQ query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adid.Count(); i ++ )
{
      var dd = adid[i];
      var cc = (from a in context.Ads where a.AdID == dd select a).ToList();

      ads.Add(cc);     // error appears here
};
```

error appears in the `ads.Add(cc);` line.

> error: the best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(Agahii.Ads) has some Invalid arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Add` method is used to add a single object.

Try `AddRange` instead, which allows you to add a list:

```
ads.AddRange(cc);
```

---

You can shorten the whole method with some LINQ. Something like this should work:

```
var ads = context.Ads.Select(a => adid.Contains(a.AdID)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ads.AddRange(cc);
```

because `cc` is a list, not an element.